# rxjs subscription fires but angular doesn't render binded result

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

rxjs subscription calling a get with a correct result. Subsciption fires (console out write console) but angular doesn't render binded result first time, second time render first result third time fires second and so on. subscription is a rxjs Subscription object. staticDeviceService is not shared with other components. what else I don't know

```
getPlants(pageNewDevice:number, pageDevice:number):void {
    if(pageDevice < 0){
      return;
    }
    if(pageNewDevice <0){
      return;
    }
    this.subscription = this.staticDeviceService.getPlants(pageNewDevice, pageDevice).subscribe((resPlants)=>{
      console.log("write console")
      this.devices = resPlants.deviceList
    })
```

}

I found the problem! This happens because when I generate the component by default (mabye cause rxjs??) change detection has setted with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.
I used a global array initialized at empty devices =[];
when the observable trigger and assign this.device = resPlants.deviceList angular does not trigger change first time, I need to push?? It works if I declare device; instead of device =[];
now the point is:
It's a best practise use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush or is better use angular default ChangeDetectionStrategy with rxjs?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bz1yhj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy)?

Comment: you could try to inject `ChangeDetectionRef` and then inside of a subscription call `cdRef.markForCheck();`

Comment: Please move the second paragraph into an answer post.